# How can I split my Apache 2.4 error_log into separate logs using a $SESSION value?

Tags: apache, perl, session, cgi, error-log

Our web app stores a session value to indicate a client's location using the CGI::Application::Plugin::Session module. This value is not part of the url and we do not need or want to use virtual hosts for each location. I want to have Apache split the error_log into separate "location" logs in real-time, not by using or creating a post processing parser. I thought the way to go would be by piping the logging to an external program to handle the split, using the syntax below, but I'm not sure how to access the session location value via that external program during run-time:

```
ErrorLog "|/usr/local/etc/apache24/some_program.pl"
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible.  We use the following config to filter out some noise from our apache logs:

```
ErrorLog    "|/etc/httpd/conf/apache_log_handler.pl >> /service/httpd-err/s"
```

Where our custom `apache_log_handler.pl` looks like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$|=1;
my $warning_message_to_drop_reg = qr/constant subroutine.+redefined|prototype mismatch|^\s+at\s+\/\w+/i;

while (<STDIN>) {
    my $message = $_;
    next if ($message =~ /$warnings_message_to_drop_reg/);

    # You should add custom code here, to write to other locations, if desired
    # If you log your session id, you can grab it here to decide what to do.

    print $message; # Goes to normal apache error log

}
```

Comment: The message you are filtering on is not going to contain the session value I need. It's in the session itself not stdin. Furthermore, I dont want to add data to the stdin stream (like the location). I just want to know if there is a way to access the session that is producing the stream.

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/418110/how-to-log-session-id-into-apache-http-server-access-log for how to add the session id to the apache log.
You can either handle this in the apache logger, or within the code that handles the request (and omit the logging messages).